# Creating Fixed Width File in R with unique positions for each element

Tags: r, file, flat-file

I have data

```
structure(list(Animal = c("dog", "cat", "dog ", "cat"), Fur = c("no", 
"no", "yes", "yes"), Color = c("Pearl", "Midnight ", "Midnight ", 
"Pearl")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

I am trying to create a fixed with text file, but I want to have some of the columns up unique amounts of space. So let's say I want the `Animal` column to be from positions 1-10, but I want `Fur` to be in 50-54, and then I want `Color` to be in 100-120. How would I go about doing this in R?

Comment: those should be blank

Comment: Why do you have trailing spaces in one of the "dog " and "Midnight " ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `str_pad` to create a fixed length string

```
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
library(dplyr)
out <- df1 %>%
   mutate(across(everything(), trimws)) %>% 
   add_row(!!! setNames(names(df1), names(df1)), .before = 1) %>% 
   pmap_chr( ~ {
            cn1 <- str_pad(..1, width = 10, pad = " ", side = "left")
            blnk <- strrep(" ", 39)
            cn2 <- str_pad(..2, width = 5, pad = " ", side = "left")
            blnk2 <- strrep(' ', 45)
            cn3 <- str_pad(..3, width = 21, pad = " ", side = "left")
           str_c(cn1, blnk, cn2, blnk2, cn3)
   })
```

Comment: how do you save the file to be a fixed text file afterwards where all the columns have a specific position?

Comment: @rj44 you may use `write` to a .txt file

Comment: and if I use side=right then all of the data should be at the start of the position required then yes?

Comment: @rj44 yes, that is correct

Answer (score 2):

Loop through columns pad each with matching width:

```
# set widths
w <- c(10, diff(c(10, 54, 120)))

# pad every column with matching width
x <- do.call(paste0, lapply(seq(w), function(i){ formatC(trimws(df[, i ]), width = w[ i ]) }))

# output
write(x, file = "tmp.txt")
```

**tmp.txt**

```
       dog                                          no                                                             Pearl
       cat                                          no                                                          Midnight
       dog                                         yes                                                          Midnight
       cat                                         yes                                                             Pearl
```